# Advance slideshow manually with jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, slideshow

please be easy - first post!

Looking to modify the following script:
http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

Love it's simplicity, trying to find a way to add an advance function

Preferably on the img or div - on click or from a link.

Any suggestions?

Appreciate the help

**edit**, below is the script and here is a link to a working version:

[link to a live testing page](http://bit.ly/nvUr8w)

script:

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

// use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

// uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

// var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
// var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
// var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );

});
```

style:

```
#slideshow {
position:relative;
height:350px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:8;
opacity:0.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
z-index:10;
opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
z-index:9;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="slideshow">
        <img src="image01.jpg" width="262" height="496" border="0" class="active" />
        <img src="image02.jpg" width="262" height="496" border="0" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do this by changing the interval to a timeout, which gives us an id which we can reset at will. Then we can use a click even to reset this interval and advance manually, which in turn will start up the interval again.

Using the simplest example on [jonraasch.com](http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow):

```
window.slideInterval = null;

function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
    var $next = $active.next();    

    $next.addClass('active');

    $active.removeClass('active');

    window.slideInterval = setTimeout('slideSwitch()', 5000 )
}

jQuery(function() {
    window.slideInterval = setTimeout('slideSwitch()', 5000 );
});

$(el).click(function(){
    // reset interval
    clearTimeout(window.slideInterval);

    // trigger next slide manually
    slideSwitch();
});
```

**Edit**

Over the weekend I had the time to put some more attention to this, and I read up on the best practices in making a jQuery plugin. Code is slightly documented, but all in all fairly standard and not very complex, though has a fair bit of juggling with variables :)

If you use anything you should use this.

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/RFJMy/214/

btw, you can just delete the prev and rand functions if you don't want to use them, start, stop, init and transit to make the whole work.

Comment: Thanks sg3s. I tried the jquery code with your code above and it doesn't advance nor loop the slideshow

Comment: Try some basic debugging on it. You could see this more as psuedo code, you didn't post your own code you use right now (html + images, css, javascript) so I can't tell you how to integrate it.

Comment: easy tiger! it's my first time :). i've edited my post with the code i am using. maybe that will help? thanks for trying it out !!!

Comment: @jsheps I looked over the script again and tbh to make an onclick advancer isn't hard it does require some work to make work properly... I decided to experiment with this to make it easier to initialize a very simple slideshow with variable parameters. [The result can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/STnMC/)

Comment: one thing i noticed is that it seems to "skip" or "pause" and doesn't cycle after clicking through. it could be a hover state that is pausing it?

Comment: @jsheps I made it that way, it doesn't allow you to trigger then next slide while it's already doing a fade... problem is taht it becomes a little more complex to write that.

Comment: ahhh ok i gotcha. can you point me in the right direction? thanks for all your help so far, i am starting to understand it.

Comment: Wellll since we're working with classes to keep track of the active item it would mess up the animations and eventually possibly they active item since we remove that after the animation....

Comment: It is :) Just to be clear I do this for myself as much as to help someone else. Over the weekend I had the time to clean up and properly code the slideshow. Check my edit to see a proper plugin with code which is highly reusable and has quite a few options.

Answer (score 0):

That particular sample already has an advance function built in: `slideSwitch`.  This function is called in a `setInterval` loop to advance the slide show.  All you need to do is hook up that method to your button click and you should be good to go.

HTML:

```
<div id="advanceShow">Click to Advance</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#advanceShow').click(function() {
    slideShow();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jared. I have tried this method out and it doesn't seem to work. Could it be slideshow(); that is causing an issue?

Comment: @jsheps what's happening?  Is it erroring out, is the console printing anything?

Comment: no error, does not appear to be doing anything. maybe its misnamed?

Comment: @jsheps open it up under the debugger. It will give some error

Comment: the only error message i received was 
"Warning: Error in parsing value for 'filter'. Declaration dropped"
but i believe that is unrelated

Comment: @jsheps can you send us a link to a place where this code is running?

Comment: Hi Jared. I could make a demo site tomorrow. I just posted the code I'm using in my original post in the mean time if that helps any

Comment: here was the script with your added code: http://bit.ly/oLYeT0 (currently not working)

Comment: @jsheps when I try that code it works just fine.  What problem are you seenig?